# What caused sendmail permission be modified?

Tags: sendmail, permission-denied

My OS is CentOS 6.2, I have installed sendmail for about 2 years. It always runs well and I have changed nothing. But I am not sure why today I find sendmail has already down for 5 days. in maillog, a ton of lines with `NOQUEUE: SYSERR(apache): can not chdir(/var/spool/clientmqueue/): Permission denied` (I am very confuse)

After a rescue work,

```
chown root.smmsp /usr/sbin/sendmail.sendmail
chmod g+s /usr/sbin/sendmail.sendmail
chown smmsp.smmsp /var/spool/clientmqueue
service sendmail restart
```

Now sendmail works again. But in the past 5 days, I lost a lot of mails. Are they stored in database or any logs? How to re-send these mails?

And What caused sendmail permission be modified?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is your application running on Apache?

If yes, the solution was to change the permissions of /var/spool/mclientqueue like so:

```
chmod 1777 /var/spool/clientmqueue
```

Apache does not allow setgid, hence the failure when sendmail client tries to send a mail.

Also you can try disabling Selinux, as this will conflict the permission usage.

Comment: thanks an answer. I have disabed Selinux 2 years ago, and I have checked it still disabling now. I am not sure What caused sendmail permission be modified? btw, what is the difference between `chmod 1777 /var/spool/clientmqueue` and `chmod 0777 /var/spool/clientmqueue`?

Comment: The permissions passed as an argument to chmod are specified as an octal value. Each numeral in the value represents three bits. If three numerals are given, you're setting the read, write and execute bits for the file's owner, group and others (everyone else). If four numerals are given, the leftmost number sets the setuid, setgid and sticky bits. Octal 1 sets the sticky bit.When the sticky bit is set on a directory, files in that directory may only be unlinked or renamed by root or the directory owner or the file owner